# Voting on Hacker News stories programmatically?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

I decided to write an app like: http://michaelgrinich.com/hackernews/ but for Android devices, my idea will use a web application backend (because I rather code in Python and for the web than completely in Java for Android devices).

What I have right now implemented is something like this:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080/stories.json?page=1\&stories=1
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sun, 25 Apr 2010 07:59:37 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.6.5
Content-Length: 296
Content-Type: application/json

[{"title": "Don\u2019t talk to aliens, warns Stephen Hawking", "url": "http://www.timesonline.co.uk/tol/news/science/space/article7107207.ece?", "unix_time": 1272175177, "comments": 15, "score": 38, "user": "chaostheory", "position": 1, "human_time": "Sun Apr 25 01:59:37 2010", "id": "1292241"}]
```

The next step (and final I think) is voting, my design is doing something like this:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080/stories/1 -d "vote=up" -u username:password
```

Will vote up and:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080/stories/1 -d "vote=down" -u username:password
```

Vote down.

I have no idea how to do it though... I was planning to use [Twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) but the login link is always different, e.g.:

```
http://news.ycombinator.com/x?fnid=7u89ccHKln
```

Later the Android app will consume this API.

Any experience with programmatically browsing Hacker News?

Comment: The link is different to protect against XS request forgeries, I think.

Otherwise you could post a link to http://news.ycombinator.com/delete_user?name=pg, or something else malicious, and hope an admin clicked on it. 

You may have to parse the whole page, and look for the new link names based on the HTML. Unfortunately, it looks a big AJAX heavy.

Comment: I'm the developer of http://michaelgrinich.com/hackernews/ . It's some black magic that all happens on the device, scraping the HTML directly from news.yc. A little tricky to figure out, but not that bad. Just some cleverness and cookie management. I decided not to use a backend server for a couple of reasons, the largest one being security. I'm certain that users wouldn't want their authentication credentials passed through a 3rd party-- especially the kinds of people around HN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) has a way to list all the links, and you get the links as an objects:

```
login_url = ''
for link in showlinks():
    if link.text == "login":
        login_url = link.url

go(login_url)
```

So link will be something like: `http://news.ycombinator.com/x?fnid=SvdNlGQoqo`